# Getting quizzes from Moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to get Moodle's quizzes as JSON. I've already tried

http://desenvolvimento.imd.ufrn.br/qmmoodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=cf5a6639a4431341a40e7a75d8bb9cba&wsfunction=get_quizzes_by_course&moodlewsrestformat=json&course_id=2

To get all quizzes from a specific course. And

http://desenvolvimento.imd.ufrn.br/qmmoodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=cf5a6639a4431341a40e7a75d8bb9cba&wsfunction=get_quiz&moodlewsrestformat=json&quiz_id=3

To get a specific quiz.

I don't know what is wrong in my URL.

Thanks.

Comment: What exception are you getting in response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are referring to this [document](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_web_services). If you read closely, you'll notice that it's a proposal about *how* the quiz web service *should* be written.

In fact, when I tried your query, to get all quizzes from a course, I got:

```
{"exception":"dml_missing_record_exception","errorcode":"invalidrecord",
 "message":"Can not find data record in database table external_functions.",
 "debuginfo":"SELECT * FROM {external_functions}
              WHERE name = ?\n[array (\n  0 => 'get_quiz',\n)]"}
```

Moodle didn't found the external function `get_quiz`. That means... unfortunately, as of now, Moodle *does not have* a web service for quizzes.

If you feel adventurous, and what you need is just getting the quizzes, you could implement a web service to do that. The relevant moodle table about quizzes is `mdl_quiz` (for a full schema, look at [this article](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_database_structure)), and here's the tutorial that shows how to implement it: [Adding a web service to a plugin - Moodle Docs](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin).

Comment: It's not a working API for quizzes. It's a proposal design for them. If you go in this path (in your moodle): `Site administration /
Plugins / Web services / API Documentation`, you'll see that **there's no such webservice**.

Comment: Anyway, I really hope that they implement the feature in next releases. It would come really in handy.

Comment: You can get list of course content , in that you can see quiz list also like this webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=3afe18c8697dac9518d59bb8f10429b4&wsfunction=core_course_get_contents&moodlewsrestformat=json&courseid=8

Comment: if you know about how to get list of private file from moodle default webservice here is URL which i am tray  to get webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=3afe18c8697dac9518d59bb8f10429b4&wsfunction=core_files_external&moodlewsrestformat=json&contextid=2&component=user&filearea=private&itemid=0

Answer (score 1):

**mod_quiz_get_quizzes_by_courses**
is the function that does the job. How to call it

---

```
https://yourmoodledomain/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&courseids[0]=courseid&wsfunction=mod_quiz_get_quizzes_by_courses&wstoken=yourusertoken
```

Comment: Also the one if you need to retrieve the quiz settings